# How to register a new payum payment method and add actions?

Tags: php, symfony, factory, payum

I have created a payum payment method. I have set up a payment form that stores the payment details and then I generate the payment security token. This all seems ok so far and payum generates the token in storage.

However, I cannot seem to register it. I don't know where I am supposed to add the actions so they are used when payment method is loaded.

I have the following questions.

- **Where do I add a reference to my PaymentFactory?** At the moment I load the payum extension in the bundle build method and add an instance of the PaymentFactory to the extension. Is this all I need to do?
- I created a Capture and Status Action. **Where do I add those actions to the payment gateway? Do I register them in the PaymentFactory?** I added dump and exits to both classes and when I run a payment in the browser, it seems to never hit the action and exit at the point I set.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to add actions to a payment:

- The quickest is using custom factory.

  ```
  payum:
      contexts:
          you_name_it:
              custom:
                  actions:
                      - your.action.service.from.container
                      - your.another.action.service.from.container
  ```
- Create a payment factory. This is advanced technic and could be useful if you need custom configuration. For that you have to implement `PaymentFactoryInterface` and [register it to Payum extension](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/PayumBundle.php#L27). You can add actions in the factory directly (require good understanding of symfony container):

  ```
  <?php

  function create(ContainerBuilder $container, $contextName, array $config)
  {
      $paymentDefinition = new Definition;
      $paymentId = 'paymentId';

      $container->setDefinition($paymentId, $paymentDefinition);

      $paymentDefinition->addMethodCall('addAction', array(
          new Reference('your.action.service.from.container')
      ));
  }
  ```

  or you can load an xml file with actions. The actions services has to had a tag `payum.action`. The tag has to have a `factory` defined. It has to match the name of the factory you created. Example: [paypal_express_checkout_nvp.xml](https://github.com/Payum/PayumBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/payment/paypal_express_checkout_nvp.xml#L47)

  ```
  <service
      id="your.action.service.from.container"
      class="%your.action.service.from.container.class%"
      public="false"
  >
      <tag name="payum.action" factory="your_factory_name" />
  </service>
  ```

Comment: Great answer. That really helped me out!! My payment method's code is now being triggered and I figured out how to add the API I needed. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: The `contexts` key has been changed to `payments`.

Comment: Even more, In 0.15.x and later it was renamed to `gateways`.